# SQL JOIN / Merge resultant records to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I have a table with bookings which has got itemcode, each booking might have multiple records in the table with multiple itemcode. I have an `ItemMapping` table which maps to itemcode. One person might have multiple bookings too.

I want a result for only 2 itemtypes say - 1000 and 2000.

The twist is in the `ItemMapping` table:

| ItemCode | ItemName | ItemTypes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | Cell 2 | 1000 |
| CC | Cell 4 | 1000 |
| DD | Cell 5 | 2000 |
| EE | Cell 6 | 3000 |
| FF | Cell 7 | 2000 |
| BB | Cell 8 | 4000 |

Booking Table,

| BookingId | Bookingdte | ItemCode | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | March 2 | AA | John |
| 222 | June 4 | CC | David |
| 111 | March 2 | DD | John |
| 222 | June 4 | EE | David |
| 333 | MAy 10 | FF | Don |
| 111 | March 2 | BB | John |

The resultset should have the below columns,

```
BookingId, BookingDate, Name, ItemName(1000), ItemName(2000)
```

When I am looking for bookingId 111, The result should be
111, March 2, John,Cell 2, Cell 5

But I am getting 2 rows,
111, March 2, John,NULL, Cell 5
111, March 2, John,Cell 2, NULL

The result I get is, one row for `ItemName(1000)` and another row for `ItemName(2000)`, but I want the result in a single row.

Can any of you guide me on this ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B.BookingID, B.BookingDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN B.ItemCOde = 1000 
            THEN ISNULL(I.ItemName, I.ItemName) 
    END AS ItemName(1000),
    CASE 
        WHEN B1.ItemCOde = 2000 
            THEN ISNULL(I1.ItemName, I1.ItemNAme) 
    END AS ItemName(2000)
FROM
    BOOKINGS B
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemMapping I ON I.COde = B.ItemCode
INNER JOIN 
    Bookings B1 ON B1.BookingId = B.BookingId
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemMapping I1 ON I1.Code = B1.Itemcode
WHERE 
    B.Itemcode = 1000 
    AND B1.COde = 2000
```

Comment: please post also the bookings table i can no see what you are joining it the second time

Comment: That query will generate an error ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bfJSXbiN)). Neither of the column aliases you define are valid (without delimit identifying).

Comment: This is called conditional aggregation. it looks like: SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN something = 1000 THEN someField END) AS someField1, MAX(CASE WHEN something = 2000 THEN someField END) AS someFIeld2

Comment: When I use Max, I get only one output record, But there might be multiple records.

Comment: This is not the actual code/table. This is just a short replication for a very small logic in a big Stored procedure.

Comment: i think you should include the results you want to get

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are over-complicating this. You only need one join, and then just conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  b.BookingId,
  b.Bookingdte,
  b.Name,
  [ItemName(1000)] = MAX(CASE WHEN im.ItemTypes = 1000 THEN im.ItemName END),
  [ItemName(2000)] = MAX(CASE WHEN im.ItemTypes = 2000 THEN im.ItemName END)
FROM Booking b
JOIN ItemMapping im ON im.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
WHERE b.BookingId = 111
GROUP BY
  b.BookingId,
  b.Bookingdte,
  b.Name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xq12vWsk)

If you have multiple rows for each `ItemTypes` then you would need some way of showing all of them. You could possibly use

```sql
[ItemName(1000)] = STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN im.ItemTypes = 1000 THEN im.ItemName END, ', '),
```

Or you could maybe add a row-number and group over that as well, but your desired results are unclear.